# Component inside v-if getting data before condition is fulfilled

Tags: vue.js

I got a child-component inside a v-if block:

```
<div v-if="mappingData && mappingData.length && !loading">  
    <div v-for="element in mappingData" :key="element.attribute" >          
        <PkSelect :preselectIndex="[element.value]" 
:options="element.select_options" v-model:optionIndexModel="element.value"></PkSelect>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now to get the loading value plus the `element.select_option` values I got a recursive method:

```
        const recursiveFuzzyFill = () => {
            let awaitme = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                try {
                    if (mappingData.value[loopIndex] && fuse.search(mappingData.value[loopIndex].label).length) {
                        var refIndex = fuse.search(mappingData.value[loopIndex].label)[0].refIndex;
                        mappingData.value[loopIndex].value = refIndex;
                        console.log("Value:", mappingData.value[loopIndex].value);
                        resolve();
                    } else {
                        resolve();
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    reject();
                    loopIndex = 0;
                    return;
                }
            });

            awaitme.then(() => {
                if (loopIndex === (mappingData.value.length - 1)) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        loopIndex = 0;
                        loading.value = false;
                        console.log("Loading:", loading.value);
                    }, 5000);
                    return;
                } else {
                    loopIndex++;
                    recursiveFuzzyFill();
                }
            });
        }
```

The loading ends 5 seconds after the data is determined. Still logging the values looks like this:

```
Value: 16
PkSelect.vue:709 Preselect Index: 16
PkSelect.vue:709 Preselect Index: null
PkSelect.vue:709 Preselect Index: null
PkSelect.vue:709 Preselect Index: null
PkSelect.vue:709 Preselect Index: null
PkSelect.vue:709 Preselect Index: null
PkSelect.vue:709 Preselect Index: null
ConfigMapping.vue:184 Value: 27
ConfigMapping.vue:184 Value: 13
ConfigMapping.vue:184 Value: 18
ConfigMapping.vue:201 Loading: false
```

The select-component is receiving data even if the condition for `v-if` isn't fulfilled. How could this happen?

Comment: Then it means the condition is indeed fulfilled, try do add `loading.value = true` at the start

Comment: @Lk77 Okay, somehow just doing so worked. I added loading.value = false at the beginning of the function call. But somehow adding it inside the try-block too, solved it. Thanks tho. ^^